# Pandas: Fill the parameters in a string which is in a Pandas dataframe column by another column values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as follows:

**Edit: Based on comments and some shortcomings, I have edited the dataframe in question. The revised dataframe is as follows:**

```
ID     Static_Text                                           Params
1      Today, {0} is quite Sunny. Tomorrow, {1}              1-10-2020  
       may be little {2}
1      Today, {0} is quite Sunny. Tomorrow, {1}              2-10-2020
       may be little {2}
1      Today, {0} is quite Sunny. Tomorrow, {1}              Cloudy
       may be little {2}
2      Let's have a coffee break near {0}, if I              Balcony
       don't get any SO reply by {1}
2      Let's have a coffee break near {0}, if I              30
       don't get any SO reply by {1} mins
```

What I want to achieve is :

```
 ID                     Final Text                 
  1        Today, 1-10-2020 is quite Sunny. Tomorrow, 2-10-2020            
           may be little Cloudy
  2        Let's have a coffee break near Balcony, if I              
           don't get any SO reply by 30 mins
```

i.e. all params are inserted into the text.

Now there are two ways probably I can do this.

First, convert the dataframe like below,

```
 ID        Static Text                            Params
 1       Today, {0} is quite Sunny.          [1-10-2020,2-10-2020, Cloudy]
         Tomorrow, {1} may be little {2}
```

And then I write a below function:

```
 def update_text(x):
     x['Static Text'] = x['Static Text'.format(x['Params'][0],x['Params'][1],x['Params'][2])]
     rev_text = x['Static Text']
     return rev_text
df['Final Text'] = df.apply(lambda x : update_text(x),axis=1)
```

In the above method, I am trying to get the params column values in a single row as list  (as shown above). How can I achieve the same?

***Edit: As we can see that for `ID==2`, I have 2 parameters. Hence `update_text(x)` function would not work.***

Another method may be using `df['Static Text'].str.replace(r'...', 'Params',n=1)`. However, I need to find the correct `regex`.

Either way I am not able to find a concrete solution.
Can anybody help on this?

Comment: Do you think `df.groupby(['ID','Static_Text'])['Params'].agg(list).reset_index(name='Params')` ?

Comment: @jezrael: let me try that out. I was thinking `df.pivot(index='Static Text',columns='Params').reset_index()`. What do you think?

Comment: Hmm, it not create column of lists.

Comment: True, but I get the multiple columns and then concatenate. However, there would be too much of work around. Can you please tell me the `def update_text(x):` part? Will that work? Also the `len(list(Params))` can be changed. In that case how to manage the `update_text(x)` function?

Comment: I think yes, only necessary always 3 values in each list like in sample data.

Comment: @jezrael: can you please see my revised comment and try to throw some light?

Comment: @jezrael: Any luck on how to update the `update_text()` function?

Answer (score 0):

Any luck on this? I think `update_text()` function needs to be modified as understood to perform dynamically manage the parameters in the string.