# Python: Replace angular bracket and its string within by curl bracket in each row in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

This has a reference to [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64171802/python-pandas-dynamically-fill-in-values-in-string-in-each-row-using-parameters/64171974?noredirect=1#comment113480740_64171974) .

For the sake of newness, I am reproducing the dataframe with a small change:

```
ID         Static_Text                                           Params
1      Today, <adj1> is quite Sunny. Tomorrow, <adj2>           1-10-2020  
       may be little <adj3>
1      Today, <adj1> is quite Sunny. Tomorrow, <adj2>           2-10-2020
       may be little <adj3>
1      Today, <adj1> is quite Sunny. Tomorrow, <adj2>           Cloudy
       may be little <adj3>
2      Let's have a coffee break near <adj1>, if I              Balcony
       don't get any SO reply by <adj2>
2      Let's have a coffee break near <adj1>, if I               30
       don't get any SO reply by <adj2> mins
```

Now I want to replace the whole `<adj>` by `{}` where 1st occurrence of  i.e. `<adj1>` shall be replaced by `{0}`. So the resultant dataframe would look like follows:

```
ID         Static_Text                                           Params
1      Today, {0} is quite Sunny. Tomorrow, {1}              1-10-2020  
       may be little {2}
1      Today, {0} is quite Sunny. Tomorrow, {1}              2-10-2020
       may be little {2}
1      Today, {0} is quite Sunny. Tomorrow, {1}              Cloudy
       may be little {2}
2      Let's have a coffee break near {0}, if I              Balcony
       don't get any SO reply by {1}
2      Let's have a coffee break near {0}, if I              30
       don't get any SO reply by {1} mins
```

I am trying the following:

```
def replace_angular(df):
   if '<' and '>' in df['Static_Text']:
       rep_txt = re.sub(r'\<[^>]*\>',{},df[Static_Text'])
   return rep_txt

df = df.apply(lambda x : replace_angular(x),axis=1)
```

But I am not too sure about the above code snippet. Especially how to bring 0,1 etc within {}.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the number in adj over 9, should change "m.group(0)[-2]" to "m.group(0)[4:-1]".

```py
print (df["Static_Text"].str.replace(r"<adj(\d)>", lambda m: "{"+f"{int(m.group(0)[4:-1])-1}"+"}"))
```

Comment: Many Thanks. I dont want that `adj` to be part of the regex as this might change. Secondly, what if I have 15 parameters i.e. {0},{1}...{15}? How `int(m.group(0)[4:-1]` gonna help?

Answer (score 1):

IIUC you can pass a `lambda` function in `str.replace` as replacement:

```
df["Static_Text"].str.replace(r"<[A-Za-z]+(\d+)>", lambda m: '{'+f'{int(m.group(1))-1}'+'}')

0                     Today, {0} is quite Sunny. Tomorrow, {1} may be little {2}
1                     Today, {0} is quite Sunny. Tomorrow, {1} may be little {2}
2                     Today, {0} is quite Sunny. Tomorrow, {1} may be little {2}
3         Let's have a coffee break near {0}, if I don't get any SO reply by {1}
4    Let's have a coffee break near {0}, if I don't get any SO reply by {1} mins
```

Comment: Many thanks. Two questions: 1. Can I use my regex while you are using `str.replace(r"<adj(\d)>"` part? Because the word `adj` might change. 2. What exactly `{int(m.group(0)[-2])-1}` is doing? What if instead of 0,1,2 I have 0....15?

Comment: For regex i'd probably use `r"<[A-Za-z]+(\d)>"` instead. I updated the above and use `m.group(1)` instead and it should adapt to any number.

Comment: Will your regex capture any space or special character within `<adj>`? Like `<some# tag>`? Can I use `r"<[A-Za-z0-9.#$@]>"` this regex instead?